# Error validating Rails model attributes that can depend on a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, shoulda

I do not have a lot of experience with testing in Rails so I don't entirely understand how testing frameworks work under the hood.

Error I am getting:

```
Failure/Error: self.slug ||= name.parameterize
NoMethodError: 
undefined method `parameterize' for nil:NilClass
```

This error occurs even when I create a new organization with all of the attributes using FactroyGirl (or the old fashioned way with `Organization.new(...).save`).

I understand why the error is occuring, I do not understand how `name` is being evaluated as `nil` and therefore how to write the test in a way that it works properly.

I have verified that the organization and its attributes exist within the test scope using statements like `puts "short_name: #{org.short_name}"`.

```
require 'rails_helper'

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base

[....]

validates :name, :slug, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :name, :short_name, :slug, presence: true
  validates :name, length: { maximum: 255 }
  validates :short_name, length: { maximum: 20 }
  validates :slug, length: { maximum: 200 }

before_validation :generate_slug
  def generate_slug
    self.slug ||= name.parameterize
  end

  before_validation :generate_short_name
  def generate_short_name
    self.short_name ||= begin
      if name?
        if name.size > 20
          name.split(/[ -]/).first.first(20)
        else
          name
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The schema:

```
create_table "organizations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "organization_type_id",   limit: 4
    t.string   "name",                   limit: 255
    t.string   "short_name",             limit: 20
    t.string   "slug",                   limit: 200
    t.text     "description",            limit: 65535
    t.integer  "year_founded",           limit: 2, unsigned: true
    t.datetime "last_published_date"
    t.date     "notification_sent_date"
    t.datetime "last_imported_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

The organization factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :organization, class: Organization do
    name 'Example & Co'

    trait :all_fields do
      slug 'example-co'
      short_name 'Example & Co'
      description ‘This is a description.’
      year_founded 2010
    end
  end
end
```

All of the following validation tests are working on other organization attributes.
The generate_slug method is supposed to create a url safe slug from the name attribute if a slug is not provided by the user.
NOTE: I am not the author of the code, I am only building out a test suite for an app built by contractors.

Tests:

This first test is passing, I included it for information/verification

```
RSpec.describe Organization, :type => :model do

  #validating my factory:      
  describe 'FactoryGirl' do
    it 'factory generating all fields should be valid' do
      create(:organization, :all_fields).should be_valid
      build(:organization, :all_fields).should_not be_valid
    end

    it 'factory generating name field should be valid' do
      create(:organization).should be_valid
      build(:organization).should_not be_valid
    end
  end
```

The tests that are erroring out:

```
describe 'name' do
  let(:org) {FactoryGirl.build(:organization, :all_fields)} 
  context 'is valid' do
    # this is the only test on #name that fails
    it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
  end
end

describe 'slug' do
  let(:org) {FactoryGirl.build(:organization, :all_fields)}
  context 'is valid' do
    # this is the only test on #slug that fails,     
    it { should validate_presence_of(:slug) }
  end
end

describe 'short_name' do
  # All of the tests on short_name fail
  let(:org) {FactoryGirl.build(:organization, :all_fields)}
  context 'is valid' do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:short_name) }
    it { should have_valid(:short_name).when(org.short_name, 'Example & Co') } 
    it { should validate_length_of(:short_name).is_at_most(20) }      
  end

  context 'is not valid' do
    it { should_not have_valid(:short_name).when('a' * 21) }       
  end
end
```

Comment: I see that you created a test to validate the correctness of your factory. Thankfully there is an option in `FactoryGirl` to this automatically now. https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#linting-factories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First:

You need to set the right subject in your tests. This is the object to which all `it` one-liners will refer to. You did create a `let`, but since you never explicitly set it as subject, the test picked up the implicit subject (which defaults to Organization.new in your case)

To set an explicit subject you can write:

```
describe 'name' do
  subject { FactoryGirl.build(:organization, :all_fields) } 

  it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
  # or with the new syntax
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:name) }
end
```

You can read more about implicit vs explicit subject and one-liners here: http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/subject/one-liner-syntax

Second:

The other issue is that, assuming you are using the `shoulda-matchers` gem, it will set the `name` to `nil` in order to see that when the attribute is not present, a validation error should occur.

But when the name is set to nil, the before_validation callback throws an error, since it assumes always to find `name`.

You could modify the callback like this ([example in rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)):

```
before_validation :generate_slug
def generate_slug
  self.slug ||= name.parameterize if attribute_present?("name")
end
```

Third:

A suggestion. If you have the factories set up and you have the shoulda-matchers gem, you can write pretty concise specs. For example like this.

```
RSpec.describe Organization, :type => :model do
  # If you fix the callback you don't even need 
  # to set explicit subject here

  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:name) }
  it { is_expected.to validate_lenght_of(:name).is_at_most(255) }
  ... etc

  # Add custom contexts only for the before_validation callbacks,
  # because shoulda-matchers cannot test them.
  # One possible way (there are different ways and opinions on how
  # should implement this kind of test):
  describe '#slug' do
    let(:organization) { described_class.new(name: 'Ab cd', slug: slug) }

    before { organization.valid? }

    subject { organization.slug }

    context 'when it is missing' do
      let(:slug) { nil }
      let(:result) { 'ab_cd' }

      it 'gets created' do
        expect(subject).to eq(result)
      end
    end

    context 'when it is not missing' do
      let(:slug) { 'whatever' }

      it "won't change" do
        expect(subject).to eq(slug)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

For more examples you can browse [the `shoulda-matchers` documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validate_presence_of_matcher.rb).

Comment: Good stuff! Thank you! I would love any links that can explain how test frameworks are structured. For example I have seen references to ''subject" in gem documentation but nothing that explained what it is or how to use it. Cheers!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the comment: "# add custom contexts only for the before_validation callbacks" ?

Comment: I updated the example on the before_validation callback part. That is the way I myself would create something like that, but there are different approaches. (like always in testing..). Hope that helps!

Comment: Where to find more info? The official RSpec documentation is great place, but the information is a somewhat scattered around, so it can be hard to form a general picture on how to use the framework. Also RSpec has gone through quite many changes since the past few years, so many older tutorials are probably not up to date on their rspec anymore. Besides that you can also counter quite many styles of writing those specs. Mocking vs not mocking, instance variables vs lets, don't/do use shared_examples, etc. So if you encounter differences, it is probably because of the above reasons.

Comment: [This repo](https://github.com/everydayrails/rails-4-1-rspec-3-0) has pretty nice basic examples for testing a basic Rails app. Though I would still look at it critically as well. When thinking about what to test or how to test, try to remember that that, your specs should bring the most value to you as developer (makers refactoring easier, gives you confidence on that everything will work the right way, even the corner cases) and create the specs that make most sense for you.